# How to soft delete on condition?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have implemented soft delete in my Entity, need to delete category if she is empty (does not have banners).

I use annotation `@SQLDelete` and `@Where` to override the delete method.

```
@Entity
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE Category SET deleted = true WHERE id=?")
@Where(clause = "deleted=false")
@Table(name = "Category")
public class Category extends BaseModelEntity {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Set<Banner> banners = new HashSet<>();

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String req_name;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private boolean deleted = Boolean.FALSE;

}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class CategoryService {
    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    public void remove(int id, Category category){
        if(category.getBanners().isEmpty()) {
            categoryRepository.deleteById(id);
        } else {
            System.out.println("don't remove");
        }
    }
}
```

I am using a test to check are there any banners in the category
Test:

```
    @Test
    public void deleteCategory() {
        Category category = new Category();
        category.setName("test1");
        category.setReq_name("test2");

        Banner banner = new Banner(category);
        banner.setName("first");
        banner.setPrice(8.2);
        banner.setText("");


        Banner banner1 = new Banner(category);
        banner1.setName("second");
        banner1.setPrice(8.2);
        banner1.setText("");


        categoryRepository.save(category);
        bannerRepository.save(banner1);

        Assertions.assertFalse(category.getBanners().isEmpty());
    }
}
```

I get error, what category is empty,but i inject category in constructor banners.

```
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
    Expected :false
    Actual   :true
```

Where did I go wrong? When testing this method category is delete when she contains banners.

Comment: When asking a question it is best to provide: what did you do, what did you expect to happen, what actually happened.
Also if you "implemented soft delete in my entity" please show with your code what you mean by that

Comment: What's the problem? If you don't tell us expected and actual behavior we can't tell what's wrong. Also, what does `deleteById()` do? Is it the standard implementation that actually deletes the entity which would be a hard delete?

Comment: Can you please share the code/annotation for `Category` class  ? Are you using `@SQLDelete` annotation ?

Comment: @Santosh yep, i update queshion

Comment: How are you retrieving the category, when you retrieve it from the DB, do you lazy initialize the banners?

Comment: @OsamaAbdulRehman yes, i use fetchtype.Lazy

Comment: then make sure by the time remove is called, category's banners are lazy initialized

Comment: @OsamaAbdulRehman i check changing fetchtype.Eager bot nothing changed, that's not the point

Comment: Enable the debug logs for Hibernate/JPA and check whats happening.

Comment: @Santosh update queshion

Comment: @Saintka, please enable the debug log, check what queries are being fired to the database.